# How completion handler work under the hood

Tags: swift, closures, completion

I'm trying to understand how completion get called with asynchronous code

With synchronous code, it is simple, we have run code from top to bottom, from line to line like this:

```
func work(completion: () -> Void) {
    // do work 1 
    // do work 2
    completion()
}
```

But with the task that takes time? I think it works just like the above example, let's consider the following example. Here, I mimic the `dataTask` function:

```
func dataTask(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (URLResponse?) -> Void) {
    preparing parameters
    sendingRequest // -> for example, it took 10s
    // -> Here, the thread blocked for waiting the response from server
    // After received the response from server (10s), thread unblocked and run the next line
    completionHandler(URLResponse())
}
```

That's how I think how completion handler work. It is right? If I'm wrong, can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works if your thread blocking works correctly (i.e. the breakpoint hits that line after all your async stuff is done).

Here, `completionHandler` is a value type called a closure in Swift. It behaves kind of like lambdas/anonymous functions/etc. (The "kind of" refers to how it plays with Swift's garbage collection, ARC, which works differently from other popular languages. That's a separate topic though.).

These closures are essentially function pointers, so you are basically injecting a function as a parameter that can be used within your function.

In other words, it's like giving your function a box with a button to press. Your function can press that button whenever it wants as long as it can provide the necessary inputs. In this case, a `URLResponse?` is needed to press that button. When that button is pressed, the caller of this function will have whatever code block it defined executed (synchronously, or sometime in the future).

Because your question involves "under the hood"
I recommend reading some Swift [documentation][1]. If there's something you don't understand, go ahead and comment here. Other people spent hours refining that page with great details and behaviors that I can't reasonably mimic here.

Pro tip: Don't forget to use `[weak self]`!!!

**COMMENT RESPONSE:**

> thank you very much, but I still have one more question: you said "if your thread blocking works correctly", but in ordinary case, will it happen? I mean, if I do nothing about blocking thread, adding break point,... is it happen? - phuongzzz

Let's look at this example:

```
//You can copy-paste the following into a playground
import Foundation

//MARK:- FUNCTIONS

//Here's a buggy function
func intentionallyBuggyFunction(onDone: @escaping (String) -> ())
{
    var resultTxt = "Oops the async did not happen"

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
    {
        resultTxt = "The async happened!"
    }
    onDone(resultTxt)
}
//Here's one that'll async properly (this example is just for demonstration purposes)
func thisOneWillWork(onDone: @escaping (String) -> ())
{
    let thread = DispatchQueue(label: "Bambot", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent,
                               autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
    thread.async {[onDone]
        var resultTxt = "Oops the async did not happen"
        let dg = DispatchGroup()

        dg.enter()
        thread.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
        {[weak dg] in
            resultTxt = "The async happened!"
            dg?.leave()
        }
        dg.wait()
        onDone(resultTxt)
    }
}

//MARK:- CODE EXECUTION

//This'll print the wrong result
intentionallyBuggyFunction { (resultStr) in
    print(resultStr)
}
//This'll print the right result
thisOneWillWork { (resultStr) in
    print(resultStr)
}
```

As you can see, the first function will queue the async stuff, immediately execute the closure, and then hit its ending function brace. The function finishes executing before the async stuff can happen even though the closure is escaping.

The second function actually instructs the device to wait for pending updates on a separate thread. That way, the String is updated before the closure is called.

Now, the second function is, I would consider, spaghetti code. It's not good practice to just willy-nilly spin up a DispatchQueue like this because iOS only has so many threads in its pool to choose from. It's also misusing DispatchGroup (for behavior like this, you should make a serial queue (you can Google that)).

It's better to just capture the completion handler `{[onDone](...) in` and then call it inside the actual async block like so:

```
//Better async (cleaner, makes more sense, easier to read, etc.)
func betterAsync(onDone: @escaping (String) -> ())
{
    var resultTxt = "Oops the async did not happen"

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
    {[onDone] in
        resultTxt = "The async happened!"
        onDone(resultTxt)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I still have one more question: you said "if your thread blocking works correctly", but in ordinary case, will it happen? I mean, if I do nothing about blocking thread, adding break point,... is it happen?

Comment: I'll update my answer with an edit ^

Comment: What an answer! You're my hero :)